# Php input redirection if and else statment

Tags: php, redirect

Can somebody help me fix this simple php redirections using input values username and password. here is my php ;

```
    <?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (strcmp($username, "3495062250") && strcmp($password, "00238746") )
    {
        header("location: /client_349***506/index.html");
    }
    else{ header("location: password-error.html");
    }
    //Next User Goes here
if (strcmp($username, "3491038403") && strcmp($password, "02993219") )
    {
        header("location: /client_349***403/index.html");
    }
    else{ header("location: phoneconfirmation.html");
    }
//Next User Goes here
if (strcmp($username, "3496574930") && strcmp($password, "49830283") )
    {
        header("location: /client_349***543/index.html");
    }
    else{ header("location: phoneconfirmation.html");
    }
?>
```

Comment: If you don't do a `die` after the header call, script execution will continue after that specific line and your other elses will get executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only think i see there that can fail is when you call `header("location: whatever")` you type "location" when it should be "Location". Maybe that's the reason why it doesn't work. See the `header:` doc [here](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php).